# No getter method available for property for bean with name

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts, javabeans

I'm trying to populate a select with Struts. However, I'm getting this error message:
No getter method available for property label under name `com.packagename.branchImpl`
There is no variable called 'label' in the class in which its looking either, so I don't know how it is looking for `label`

form class is a very typical entity class

any suggestions as to why this error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a typo with `<cain:optionsCollection` should be [`<html:optionsCollection`](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/optionsCollection.html). The last tag uses a `property` attribute for the collection of beans that have `label` and `value` properties. If you have a different property names in the collection bean then it could be specified using the `label` and `value` attributes of the tag. For example if you have a collection `List<MyBean>` and

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
  private String key;
  private String name;
  //getters and setters for both

}
```

then you should use

```
<html:select name="querySwiftLogForm" property="branch" >
    <html:optionsCollection name="querySwiftLogForm"  property="branchList" label="name" value="key"/> 
</html:select>
```

If you don't have a bean that you could use with the collection, then you could use [`LabelValueBean`](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/util/LabelValueBean.html). And you need to fill the collection with the instances of that bean. Then `lable` and `value` attributes not necessary for that bean because it will use the defaults.

Also, if you use the form that is mapped to the action then `name` attribute is not necessary.

Comment: thank you to the two of you Roman and JB. You were right, i needed to set the label and value, but i also had removed the custom tag and used normal html:optionsCollection. We'll worry about the company custom tags another day!

Answer (score 1):

> No getter method available for property for bean with name

I'm not posting complete error and jsp and all so just understand

- First Check properties file if you are using it.
- Then check properties name -- like  **name, password**
- And check the setter and getter method where you define. Check very carefully.
- Then you find that setter and getter are different then it should be

For example:

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

While it would be as:

```
public void setname(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
public String getname()
{
    return name;
}
```

Just a little mistake while using setter and getter.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a label property because that's what [`optionsCollection`](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html%3aoptionsCollection) does:

> This tag operates on a collection of beans, where each bean has a label property and a value property. The actual names of these properties can be configured using the label and value attributes of this tag.